# Fail to run trainer.train() with huggingface transformer

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, squad

I am trying to set up a TensorFlow fine-tune framework for a question-answering project. Using hugging-face/transformer as the prototype, but cannot run through the trainer.

The experiment is conducted at Databricks, the pre-trained model loaded is base-bert, train and dev sets are downloaded from hugging-face examples SQUAD 2.0 https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/tree/master/examples/question-answering

The error log complains about the unexpected keyword argument '**is_impossible**', which is a SQUAD 2 data format feature.

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = TFAutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

processor = SquadV2Processor()

train_examples = processor.get_train_examples(data_dir, train_file_name)
eval_examples = processor.get_dev_examples(data_dir, dev_file_name)

train_dataset = (squad_convert_examples_to_features(
            examples=train_examples,
            tokenizer=tokenizer,
            max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
            doc_stride=doc_stride,
            max_query_length=max_query_length,
            is_training=True,
            return_dataset="tf"
        )) 

eval_dataset = (squad_convert_examples_to_features(
            examples=eval_examples,
            tokenizer=tokenizer,
            max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
            doc_stride=doc_stride,
            max_query_length=max_query_length,
            is_training=False,
            return_dataset="tf"
        )) 

training_args = (TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir, 
    num_train_epochs=2,
    do_train=True, 
    per_device_train_batch_size = 8, 
    per_device_eval_batch_size = 16,
    logging_steps=10, 
    learning_rate=3e-5))

trainer = TFTrainer(model=model, args=training_args, train_dataset=train_dataset, eval_dataset=eval_dataset)

trainer.train()
```

### **Error Log as below:**

> ---
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 trainer.train()
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer_tf.py
> in train(self)
> 410             if self.args.past_index >= 0:
> 411                 self._past = None
> --> 412             for step, training_loss in enumerate(self._training_steps(train_ds, optimizer)):
> 413                 self.global_step = iterations.numpy()
> 414                 self.epoch_logging = epoch_iter - 1 + (step + 1) / steps_per_epoch
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer_tf.py
> in _training_steps(self, ds, optimizer)
> 457         Returns a generator over training steps (i.e. parameters update).
> 458         """
> --> 459         for i, loss in enumerate(self._accumulate_next_gradients(ds)):
> 460             if i % self.args.gradient_accumulation_steps == 0:
> 461                 self._apply_gradients(optimizer)
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer_tf.py
> in _accumulate_next_gradients(self, ds)
> 490         while True:
> 491             try:
> --> 492                 yield _accumulate_next()
> 493             except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
> 494                 break
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
> 566         xla_context.Exit()
> 567     else:
> --> 568       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> 569
> 570     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
> in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
> 613       # This is the first call of **call**, so we have to initialize.
> 614       initializers = []
> --> 615       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
> 616     finally:
> 617       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
> in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
> 495     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
> 496         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
>
> ## pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> --> 497             *args, **kwds))
> 498
> 499     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
> in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args,
> **kwargs)
> 2387       args, kwargs = None, None
> 2388     with self._lock:
> -> 2389       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
> 2390     return graph_function
> 2391
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
> in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
> 2701
> 2702       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
> -> 2703       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
> 2704       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
> 2705       return graph_function, args, kwargs
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py
> in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
> override_flat_arg_shapes)
> 2591             arg_names=arg_names,
> 2592             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
> -> 2593             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
> 2594         self._function_attributes,
> 2595         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
> func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
> arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
> override_flat_arg_shapes)
> 976                                           converted_func)
> 977
> --> 978       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
> 979
> 980       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py
> in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
> 437         # **wrapped** allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
> 438         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
> --> 439         return weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
> 440     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
> 441
>
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
> 967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
> --> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
> 969             else:
> 970               raise
>
> TypeError: in converted code:
>
> ```
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer_tf.py:488
> ```
>
> _accumulate_next  *
> return self._accumulate_gradients(per_replica_features, per_replica_labels)
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer_tf.py:498
> _accumulate_gradients  *
> per_replica_loss = self.args.strategy.experimental_run_v2(
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/distribute/one_device_strategy.py:180 experimental_run_v2
> return super(OneDeviceStrategy, self).experimental_run_v2(fn, args, kwargs)
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer_tf.py:511
> _forward  *
> per_example_loss, _ = self._run_model(features, labels, True)
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/trainer_tf.py:532
> _run_model  *
> outputs = self.model(features, training=training, **labels)[:2]
> /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-f56565e5-e45b-447a-b7df-50daf9109495/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:778
> **call**
> outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>
> ```
> TypeError: tf__call() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_impossible'
> ```

Comment: Aren't you missing `version_2_with_negative=True` as parameter?

Comment: @cronoik  should not be caused by that, because version_2_with_negative is used to define version of processor in run_tf_squad.py " processor = SquadV2Processor() if data_args.version_2_with_negative else SquadV1Processor() " . In above code already define processor = SquadV2Processor()

Comment: Yes you are right. I tried yesterday to launch the unchanged script with `version_2_with_negative` and it also run into an error. Maybe it is still work in progress (or I made a mistake)?